# Sass watch multiple files and folders

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have the following files tree

- sass

  - main.scss
  - bg

    - colores.scss
    - style.scss
- www

  - lib

    - ionic

      - scss

        - bg

          - ionic.scss
  - css

    - bg

      - ionic.app.min.css
      - style.css
      - androidEspecial.css
    - main.css

I need a file with all application colors. So, I made colores.scss. I need a way to watch changes in that file, and, if it changed, compile **more than one scss**.

I was wondering if there's a way to watch for *sass/bg/colores.scss*, and, if it changes, compile *sass/main.scss*, and also *www/lib/ionic/scss/bg/ionic.scss*.

I could do that mannualy, but that's not the point.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using partials.
use _colores.scss

And import this partials in your main.scss

Comment: If a partial changes it triggers the watch event of it's parent scss file?